# How to generate road curvature from the Points to path tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, route, points-to-line

I have been working on a project and I have used the `"Points to path"` tool in the processing toolbox to connect multiple points up along a route on the road network.

However, when processing this function it connects my points together but it only works in straight lines between sets of points. What I want is to have the lines between points follow the roads (routes) that would be used to reach the points.

I am currently running QGIS 3.2.2, I have tried searching the online forums to find the solution to no avail this may be down to my wording of the search.

Comment: unfortunately, this is not as trivial as one might think, and the answer is most likely that you need proper network routing. QGIS 3.x introduced the `Shortest path` function family, but without serious scripting (i.e. *pyqgis*) you will have to pay with plenty of lifetime to get your routes between and along each via point... a more versatile option would be to move to PostgreSQL/PostGIS and pgRouting, but if you´re new to that, well, lifetime will be spent then on getting familiar with it. most certainly *way* better spent, though!

Comment: You have to smooth lines. Your points must be on intersection of two lines to get proper curvature.